# Can't play skeletal animation at all

Tags: three.js

im using three.js revision 71.
i exported a model from blender, that has 2 animations.

here is the code im using (apart from generic scene stuff):

```
//THE CYLINDER
loader.load("flipping cylinder.json",function(geometry,materials)
{
    var material=new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
    flipcyl=new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry,material);
    scene.add(flipcyl);

    anim=new THREE.Animation(flipcyl,flipcyl.geometry.animations[0]);
});

//UPDATE AND RENDER
function render()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    var delta=clock.getDelta();
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);

    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();
```

i also have this in the HTML part:
    `<button onclick="anim.play();">play</button>`

everything renders ok but nothing seems to change when clicking the button, or when i input *anim.play()* in the console.

(please forgive me for any english mistakes - im not a native english speaker...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add this line while loading:

```
material.skinning = true;
```

And that's all! ;)

Comment: Besides, I have the same scenario (2 animations) but the exporter gives two animations that have the same data (I've compared them in the json file with a tool). I mean, the same animation is exported twice. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Wow that's it?! Thank you very much! You totally saved me! =)

Comment: Please, can you tell me which exporter do you use? Thanks!